# Generated SQL in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a users table and a positions table and they have relationship in my Model.

User model

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function position()
    { 
        return $this->belongsTo('Position');
    }
}
```

Position model

```
class Position extends Eloquent {
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }
}
```

I try to do this.

```
$users = User::find(1);
echo $users->lastname . "<br>"; // output the lastname
echo $users->position->name . "<br>"; // output the position name
echo $users->toSql(); // output "Select * from user"
```

My question is how can I get the generated raw SQL? something like

```
select s.* from users s left join positions p on p.id = s.position_id where s.id = 1
```

Im using Eloquent standalone. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DB::enableQueryLog();`, then try `DB::getQueryLog();` and you'll get an array which you can use. Let me know if that works!

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::enableQueryLog();

$users = User::find(1);
echo $users->lastname . "<br>"; // output the lastname
echo $users->position->name . "<br>"; // output the position name

foreach(DB::getQueryLog() as $item){
    echo $item["query"] .  "<br>";
}
```

Comment: is DB facade available in standalone eloquent? It is not working  and it throws error like DB class could not found..

Comment: @jaytemp Make sure to include the right path to the DB class in your file. Did an update